# Call method after ActionResult in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to MVC stuff, so my thinking might be completely wrong, but I would like to achieve when I call an action in a controller, as soon as it returns a result, another method will be invoked.

Currently my code is working on this way:

```
[HttpGet("/api/compile/{*path}")]
public IActionResult Compile(string path)
{
    this.Queue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async token =>
    {
        await cp.Compile()
                .ContinueWith((compilation) =>
                    Console.WriteLine(compilation.Result), token);
    });

    return new ContentResult
    {
        Content = "<div>Compilation requested...</div>",
        ContentType = "text/html"
    };
}
```

It's working as expected, a background job has been enqueued and the contentresult will be returned.

My problem is that if I check the console log, of course because of a reasonable reason, the background job starts logging in the console earlier than the contentresult has been returned, so what I see:

```
backgroundjob log...1
backgroundjob log...2
[compilation.Result]
backgroundjob log...3
backgroundjob log...4
...
```

But I would like to reach, that the background job will be enqueued strictly after the return of the result.

```
[compilation.Result]
backgroundjob log...1
backgroundjob log...2
backgroundjob log...3
backgroundjob log...4
...
```

Maybe I can add a `Thread.Sleep` inside the background job anonymous method, but of course it's not consistent and fine-logic way but currently I don't know how I can solve this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: See Action Filters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1. You can use the `OnActionExecuted()`.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!